# In ps -ef command in last column that is CMD column shows -ksh. What does this -ksh mean?

Tags: unix, ps

In ps -ef command in last column that is CMD column shows -ksh. What does this -ksh mean?

Sample: 
 arw 16107     1  0  Feb 17  pts/0     0:00 -ksh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means korn shell.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell

And the minus in front means, it was invoked as a login shell.

man ksh says:
"If the shell is invoked by exec(2), and the first character of argument zero ($0) is -, then the shell is assumed to a  login shell and commands are read from /etc/profile and then from either .profile in the current directory or        $HOME/.profile, if either file exists.

Comment: it means that one korn shell is running? If any script name is given then it means script is running in background right?

Comment: if that's the only entry: yes. At least for this user. And script names mean running scripts. They may be running in another shell in foreground, but seen from the current shell: yes, they run in background.